# Typed DataSet row creation doubt

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, strongly-typed-dataset

I've created a DataSet with 2 Data Tables exported from a DataBase with 2 related tables:

```
TableA (idTableA, name, idTableB) 
TableB (idTableB)
```

Now what I want to do is to create a Data Row of the type TableA using:

```
DataSet.TableA.AddTableARow(lblTableAName.Text.Text, ??? )
```

The `???` part ask for a `DataSet.TableBRow`, that I want to be give from a Drop Down List from the page form that is bound to a TableB TableData Data Source.

On debug I've gone trough both the Drop Down List instance and the Data Source instance, but found no DataSet.TableBRow result :(

Sorry for the confusing question, but in a more basic explanation is:

Use the Drop Down List selected TableB row to create a TableA row...

Got me?

Hope so...

Thanks

For more information:

The Drop Down List and it's Data Source code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="campaignState" runat="server" 
                                DataSourceID="CampaignStateDataSource" DataTextField="name" 
                                DataValueField="idCampaignState" />
                            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="CampaignStateDataSource" runat="server" 
                                DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" 
                                OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" 
                                TypeName="OutboundSMS.Data.OutboundSMSDataSetTableAdapters.CampaignStateTableAdapter"

                                UpdateMethod="Update">
                                <DeleteParameters>
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_idCampaignState" Type="Int32" />
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_name" Type="String" />
                                </DeleteParameters>
                                <InsertParameters>
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="idCampaignState" Type="Int32" />
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
                                </InsertParameters>
                                <UpdateParameters>
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_idCampaignState" Type="Int32" />
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="Original_name" Type="String" />
                                </UpdateParameters>
                            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: could ou put some code? specially the one binding the DropDownList to TableB, specially what is in `DataValueField`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, you are binding `DropDownList`'s `DataValueField` to `idCampaignState` column from TableB:

So, to get the `TableBRow` you have to search for it in the table using `dropDownList.SelectedItem.Value` which will contain the `idCampaignState` of that row:

for example, if `idCampaignState` is the primary key for `TableB`:

```
tableBRow = tableB.FindByidCampaignState((int)dropDownList.SelectedItem.Value)
```

More informations here:[`DropDownList Web Server Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dzka5sf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)